# is the use of spaces and/or capital letters in file names considered bad practice?

Tags: filesystems, filenames

I'm a bit old school - I never use spaces, capitals or special characters in file names, just the odd underscore for readability.
(I'm not a 8 characters + '~' extremist though!)

It used to cause lots of issues in file systems, however I see a lot of people using basically a small sentence as a file name!

certainly on web addresses, you end up with an unreadable mess of %20's.

so - is this considered bad practice, despite it not really causing many issues any more?

(don't get me started on double file extensions!! .aspx.vb)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on platform (remember Linux is also case sensitive... spaces also break filenames)...

Windows is more forgiving...

But for portability I still add _'s and make sure no spaces or funny chars.